# An unexpected error occurred when add theme

Tags: themes

I recently install wordpress using wamp on my localhost. I try to change the theme by click on add new. I just want to explore the themes but got this message:

> An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with
>   WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have
>   problems, please try the support forums.

Comment: You may need to contact your hosting provider.

Comment: @Ranuka I am install it on my localhost

Comment: Ahh sorry. I did not see it that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an error caused by trying to install it from the zip file. If it's in localhost try to unzip it and move the folder yourself to:

```
yoursite/wp-content/themes/NEWTHEME
```

And then try to switch to it from the wp-admin dashboard.